# Is each Choquet topological group strong Choquet?

Tags: gn.general-topology, topological-groups, infinite-games

A topological space $X$ is called *(strong) Choquet* if the player II has a winning strategy in the [(strong) Choquet game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choquet_game).

It is known that a metrizable space $X$ is

$\bullet$ Choquet if and only if it contains a dense complete-metrizable subspace;

$\bullet$ strong Choquet if and only if it is complete-metrizable.

Since a topological group is complete-metrizable if and only if it contains a dense complete-metrizable subspace, we obtain the following characterization.

> **Theorem.** A metrizable topological group is Choquet if and only if it is strong Choquet.
>
> **Corollary.** A cosmic topological group is Choquet if and only if it is strong Choquet.

Let us recall that a regular topological space is *cosmic* if it has a countable network of the topology. It is easy to show that a topological group is second-countable if it is cosmic and Baire. That is why Corollary follows from Theorem.

Theorem and Corollary suggest the following intriguing

> **Problem.** Is each Choquet topological group strong Choquet?

Comment: Hello, excuse me, do you have any reference for the characterization of the Choquet spaces in a metrizable space? I only knew that a Choquet space is productively Baire. Also if $X$ is a Choquet space without isolated points then $X$ contains a Cantor set.                                                                                                          
Thanks

Comment: Choquet spaces in the class of metrizable separable spaces were considered in Section 8.C of Kechris' book "Classical Descriptive Set Theory".

Comment: Thanks Professor Taras, in the hypothesis of the Theorem (8.17) of Kechris's book says that " if $X$ is a nonempty separable metrizable space and $\tilde{X}$ a Polish space in which $X$ is dense. Then $X$ is Choquet iff $X$ is comeager in $\tilde{X}$ ". How can you conclude that the result is valid for any metrizable space? Thanks

Comment: Also for the part " $X$ is comeager in $\tilde{X}$ " we don't need the hypothesis about "separability".

Comment: I think one should just repeat the classical proof: first embed the space into a complete metric space, then given a winning strategy for the Non-empty player and using the presence of a metric, to construct a tree of open sets such that the union of open sets at each level of the tree is dense and intersection of open sets at each branch is a singleton. Then the union of those singletons is a dense $G_\delta$-set (so completely-metrizable). The same proof should work for any submetrizable space (i.e. a topological space admitting a continuous metric).

Comment: Thank you so much for the idea.